# Custom comparator for Arrays.compare. Generics

Tags: java

below you find with the inner class **ArrayComparator** a simplified custom comparator for
Object arrays, which works as you will see when running the code.

Now I would like to use this comparator in method **Arrays.compare(T[] a, T[] b, Comparator<? super T> cmp)**, and modified the comparator for this purpose in
**ArrayComparator2**. The code as given below compiles nicely, but if you remove the
comment slashes of the three lines in the main method, the compiler finds *no
suitable method for compare*. How to fix this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CompareTest {

  static Object[] o1= {new Point(1,2), new Point(3,4), new Point(5,6)};
  static Object[] o2= {new Point(1,2), new Point(3,4), new Point(5,6)};

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (args.length>0) {
      if (args[0].equals("1"))
        ((Point)o2[2]).y= 7;
      else
        ((Point)o1[2]).y= 7;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<o1.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(o1[i]+", "+o2[i]);
    }
    ArrayComparator comparator= new ArrayComparator();
    int result= comparator.compare(o1, o2);
    System.out.println("Result: "+result);

//    ArrayComparator2<Object[]> comparator2= new ArrayComparator2<>();
//    result= Arrays.compare(o1, o2, comparator2);
//    System.out.println("Result: "+result);

    System.exit(0);
  }


  static class ArrayComparator implements Comparator<Object[]> {
    public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
      int l= o1.length;
      if (l!=o2.length) {
        return l>o2.length ? 1 : -1;
      }
      for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        int j= (o1[i].toString()).compareTo(o2[i].toString());
        if (j!=0) return j;
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }


  static class ArrayComparator2<T> implements Comparator<T[]> {
    public int compare(T[] o1, T[] o2) {
      int l= o1.length;
      if (l!=o2.length) {
        return l>o2.length ? 1 : -1;
      }
      for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        int j= (o1[i].toString()).compareTo(o2[i].toString());
        if (j!=0) return j;
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }


/* No solution either:
  static class ArrayComparator2<Object> implements Comparator<Object[]> {
    public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
      int l= o1.length;
      if (l!=o2.length) {
        return l>o2.length ? 1 : -1;
      }
      for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        int j= (o1[i].toString()).compareTo(o2[i].toString());
        if (j!=0) return j;
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }
*/

}
```

Comment: `ArrayComparator2<Object> comparator2= new ArrayComparator2<>();`

Comment: @Unmitigated Thanks for the quick response, but the same compiler error persists.

Comment: Change the class definition to `static class ArrayComparator2<T> implements Comparator<T>` and change the compare method.

Comment: Why do you use `Object[]` for an array that only contains `Point`?

Comment: @markspace Yes, that's not very consistent. In fact I chose Point as a simple class, whereas in reality I have a complex custom class. I wanted to avoid having suggestions for the Point class.

Answer (score 3):

From the method signature of `Arrays.compare`, it can be seen that the `Comparator` is used for comparing the array elements, not the arrays themselves. In other words, you should provide a `Comparator<T>`, not a `Comparator<T[]>`.

```
static class ArrayComparator2<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }
}
// ...
ArrayComparator2<Object> comparator2= new ArrayComparator2<>();
result= Arrays.compare(o1, o2, comparator2);
System.out.println("Result: "+result);
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works. But as I had written, my demo code is just a simplification. For the actual comparison I need to access the array elements. Simply casting to (T[])T is no way. Any other idea?

Comment: @Jörg `ArrayComparator#compare` is called with array elements. Why do you specifically need to use `Arrays.compare` for this?

Comment: And what do you hope to achieve by accessing the array itself that `Arrays.compare` is not already doing for you?

Comment: Well, since my first `ArrayComparator` class, where I can access the array elements, works, the problem is actually solved. I just wanted to see whether I can do the same with `Arrays.compare`. As this method auomatically compares lexicographically, I think I cannot use it. The ranking I have to do is with 'person' classes, each having a bunch of variables, evaluated according to various conditions.

Comment: @Jörg You can modify the compare method to compare elements the way you want.

Comment: This is good news (I think, you have `Arrays.compare` in mind). But how can I access the elements?

Comment: What do you mean? The comparator is automatically called with elements from both arrays, if you look at the source.

Comment: I did not look at the sources so far. If I have declared <T> to be an Object, how can I access it as Object array? Casting is not accepted by the compiler.

Comment: I see what you mean. What do you specifically need the arrays for though? Are you only comparing the lengths? If so, `Arrays.compare` already does that for you.

Comment: I have to decide myself according to data of person and changing conditions which one of two persons goes first.

Answer (score 1):

The `Arrays.compare()`  method does take the arrays as input with a custom comparator, but it compares the values of the arrays (upto the length of the smaller array) with the comparator you've provided. Just look at the implementation:

```
public static <T> int compare(T[] a, T[] b, Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(cmp);
    if (a == b) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a != null && b != null) {
        int length = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            T oa = a[i];
            T ob = b[i];
            if (oa != ob) {
                int v = cmp.compare(oa, ob);
                if (v != 0) {
                    return v;
                }
            }
        }

        return a.length - b.length;
    } else {
        return a == null ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

So, either you should change the class signature to:

```
static class ArrayComparator2<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }
}
```

And instantiate the comparator class as :

```
ArrayComparator2<Object> comparator2= new ArrayComparator2<>();
```

**OR**

JUST USE THE customComparator.compare() for your desired array element check and other stuffs.

```
ArrayComparator2.compare(o1,o2);
```

There's no way around.